# Best ways to Implement Caching

Tags: java, file, tomcat, caching

We have a document server with media files(jpg/pdf),These files will be retrieved for the user on UI for every request after authentication from DB . So we want to implement cache which will reduce the DB calls
Please suggest

Answer (score 1):

I´d suggest Ehcache, it is a easy library to work with.

```
ehcache.org
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want a cache that will hold a User POJO with username, password etc etc.

If you do not need to share the cache between servers I would use Guava from Google: https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/